# How can I write a multiline string into a file without adding characters to the string?

Tags: javascript, powershell, file, blob, stringify

I have a JavaScript function where I'm trying to write a PowerShell script to a PowerShell file. This is the function:

```
const script = 
`$Win32Product= Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where Name -like 'Test Client'
if ($Win32Product -eq $null){$Check=$false}else{$Check=$true}
$Hash = @{ Check = $Check }
Return $Hash | ConvertTo-Json -Compress`;

const writeStringToPowerShellFile = () => {
    const blob = new Blob([script], { type: "text/plain" });
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = "resultScript.ps1";
    link.href = url;
    link.click();
};
```

Forget about whether or not the script itself makes sense, the issue is that when I do this the ps1 file comes out with `"` and `\n` all in one line and basically just messes up the powershell command. How do I make sure that the content of the file looks exactly like this:

```
$Win32Product= Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where Name -like 'Test Client'
if ($Win32Product -eq $null){$Check=$false}else{$Check=$true}
$Hash = @{ Check = $Check }
Return $Hash | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `JSON.stringify`, because you're dealing with a string, not an object.

Try replacing:

```
const fileData = JSON.stringify(script);
const blob = new Blob([fileData], { type: "text/plain" });
```

with:

```
const blob = new Blob([script], { type: "text/plain" });
```

Comment: Okay yeah, that makes sense. Thank you, only thing is that there is whitespaces in front of the lines except the first one. Why is that? (Updated OP)

Comment: because of [backticks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), you got spaces or tabs or something in the string..So try formatting it in the editor, it takes it as is

Comment: copy/pasting and replacing the string with the one in the styled OP should come out without spaces/tabs

Comment: Ooh I see what you're saying, It works now, thank you very much!

Comment: old school way would be using string concatenation and adding newline character: `"$Win32Product= Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where Name -like 'Test Client'" + "\n" + ..the rest of the string...,` and with template literals it's improved and done automatically